# How do I remove/reset all current widgets from the database?

Tags: widgets, phpmyadmin

I recently migrated a site from a dev server to a web server and I appear to be stuck with a menu sidebar I had built in the old site that doesn't appear in the widget area of the new site's dashboard but appears on a page with side navigation regardless of settings applied.

If I add in the correct menu with styling, I end up with both menus one above the other.

I think it's something still stuck/stored in the options database.

Does anyone know how to delete/reset all widgets from phpMyAdmin?

I can see the widgets in sidebars_widgets but have read you shouldn't edit the entry directly from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: it's unlikely that it's something stuck in the database, if the sidebar was registered then it would show in the widgets interface, it's more likely that you have an empty sidebar, or that you forgot to remove something from that area in the theme template